# ¿Cómo enviar distintos campos a un webservice entre ellos un xml?

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap, wsdl

El problema es el siguiente, estoy escribiendo código para un cliente y llegue al punto de que tengo que responderle a su ws y se que no es difícil sin embargo se me dificulto cuando un campo me pide un xml, la verdad no se como responderle, ¿podrían ayudarme? agradecería cualquier ayuda ya sea un ejemplo o una lectura para poder entender esta situación, anexo el request del WS.

Estoy programando en PHP, tengo el array de los datos que debe de tener el xml incluso tengo una función que lo convierte en archivo y funciona bien, y ya tengo las variables que cumplen con la solicitud de los otros campos.

Gracias por su apoyo y tiempo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Cotizacion xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ClaEmp>int</ClaEmp>
      <ClaCte>int</ClaCte>
      <Detalle>xmlxml</Detalle>
    </Cotizacion>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Gracias @Cris223511.dev por la edición.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Normalmente cuando tienes que enviar un `XML` adentro de otro `XML` debes utilizar:

```
<![CDATA[XML que se enviará]]
```

Lo que hace `CDATA` es decirle al interprete que esa sección la analice como datos de caracteres. [Te dejo un artículo](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-tx/10.1.0?topic=reference-working-cdata-section) que te puede ser de utilidad.

Entonces lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Cotizacion xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ClaEmp>int</ClaEmp>
      <ClaCte>int</ClaCte>
      <Detalle><![CDATA[xmlxml]]</Detalle>
    </Cotizacion>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo yo solo consumo el WS no lo estoy administrando, entonces tengo problemas para mandar el xml requerido por el WS del cliente. Nuevamente muchas gracia spor tu tiempo.

Comment: Por eso, al consumirlo pones el `XML` entre `CDATA`